# Data factory custom parameters with the Resource Manager template

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template, azure-data-factory

As per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#use-custom-parameters-with-the-resource-manager-template) it is defined that we can set up the custom parameters for `datasets`, `linked services`, `pipelines` and `integration runtime`.But when I have tried, it only works for `datasets`, `linked services`  **but not for `pipelines`**

For the *pipeline settings*, I have added the below JSON section in the `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` file

```
{
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
        "*": {
            "properties": {
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "command": "="
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you follow the [correct schema for the pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories/pipelines) ? Also, what do you mean by not working? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: I can't seem to get anything happening. I have tried all sort of configurations, bu the nhsuk-searchapi-dfv2-dev-ne/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json file in the adf_publish branch has not changed at all!!

Am I doing something very wrong.

I have the file at the root of the master branch.